# Using soapUI API to create a soapUI Mock object

Tags: java, mocking, testing, soapui

I try to create a soap UI WSDL Mock Service using the soapUI API. But there seems to be no documentation of the source code.

Has anyone done this before or something in that direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I can now answer myself ... :)

I created a unit test for this task:

```
    private static WsdlProjectFactory wsdlProjectFactory;
private static WsdlInterfaceFactory wsdlInterfaceFactory;

@BeforeClass
public static void createFactories(){
    wsdlProjectFactory = new WsdlProjectFactory();
    wsdlInterfaceFactory = new WsdlInterfaceFactory();
}


@Before
public void deleteCreatedFiles() {
    new File("global-groovy.log").delete();
    new File("soapui-errors.log").delete();
    new File("soapui.log").delete();
    new File("test.xml").delete();
}

private WsdlProject project;

@Before
public void createProject() throws XmlException, IOException, SoapUIException {
    project = wsdlProjectFactory.createNew();
}

@Test @Ignore
public void testWSDLInterfaceImporting() throws SoapUIException {
    int interfaceCount = project.getInterfaceCount();
    assertThat("newly created project has no interfaces", interfaceCount, is(equalTo(0)));

    WsdlInterface[] importWsdl = wsdlInterfaceFactory.importWsdl(project, "wsdls/SimpleUseCasesellerbtainitialbtexampleMasterClient.wsdl", false);

    interfaceCount = project.getInterfaceCount();
    assertThat("newly created project has 1 interface", interfaceCount, is(equalTo(1)));
}

@Test
public void testMockCreation() throws XmlException, IOException, SoapUIException {
    int mockCount = project.getMockServiceCount();
    assertThat("newly created project has no mocks", mockCount, is(equalTo(0)));

    WsdlInterface[] importWsdl = wsdlInterfaceFactory.importWsdl(project, "wsdls/SimpleUseCasesellerbtainitialbtexampleMasterClient.wsdl", false);

    WsdlMockService service = project.addNewMockService("newMockService");
    service.addNewMockOperation(importWsdl[0].getOperationAt(0));

    project.saveAs("test.xml");

    mockCount = project.getMockServiceCount();
    assertThat("project has exactly one mock", mockCount, is(1));
}
```